# Redirect in django admin with changelist_view

Tags: python, django, redirect, django-admin, admin

I would like to redirect in django admin panel from:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/events/event/
```

to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/events/event/?date__lt=2018-6-11
```

But I got an error:

> Reverse for 'events_event_changelist' with keyword arguments '{'date__lt': datetime.date(2018, 6, 11)}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['admin/events/event/$']

Here is my code:

```
def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    if not request.method != 'GET':
        print(datetime(2018, 6, 11))
        url = reverse('admin:events_event_changelist', kwargs={'date__lt': date.today()})
        return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

Please tell me where I made mistake

Answer (score 3):

Those are not part of the URL pattern, they're just querystring arguments. Don't pass them as kwargs to reverse, append them to the result.

```
 url = '{}?date__lt={}'.format(reverse('admin:events_event_changelist'), date.today())
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I got blank page and many outputs in my terminal: `11/Jun/2018 17:32:57] "GET /admin/events/event/?date__lt=2018-06-11 HTTP/1.1" 302 0`

Answer (score 0):

Try date format 07/02/2018(Month/Date/Year)
Just like Daniel suggested (but with format):

```
url = '{}?date__lt={}'.format(reverse('admin:events_event_changelist'), datetime.date.today().strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
```